# How to apply noise to a diffuse/principled shader volume?

Tags: materials, node-editor

Basically, what I want to make is this

[image: noise applied to volumetric node]

but with a diffuse shader, rather than volume, the best I can do is this

[image]

Any idea how to help?

Comment: Not possible for now, sadly :(

Comment: Hello :). Just out of curiosity, why not use volumetrics here? It works pretty well.

Comment: @JachymMichal It looks okay at a high density, but it renders really slowly, and I can customise the material a lot better if it's solid. Is there another way to do this, maybe with something other than materials? One that actually changes the mesh?